# Node for arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to have one arrow point to another arrowhead.  How do I roughly make a node surrounding an arrowhead?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) edge [-stealth'] (1, 0);
  \path (1, 1) edge [-stealth'] (0.94, 0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, one could place a node at the `(1,0)-(.5\pgfarrowsleftextend,0)`, i.e. the end point of the arrow minus half of the total width of the `stealth'` arrow tip. But I don't know how to access the length stored in `\pgfarrowleftextend`, so the following solution involves some manual fiddling.

- Use `inner sep=<dim>` to control the radius of the circle
- Use `($(1,0)-(<dim>,0)$)` to adjust the center of the circle

## Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% \usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) edge [-stealth'] (1,0);
  \node(n)[draw,circle,inner sep=3pt]at($(1,0)-(2pt,0)$){};
  \path (1, 1) edge [-stealth'] (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Update

The above approach can be generalized to work with curves, where the node positioning option `pos=<frac>` works (e.g. the line-to and curve-to operations). The idea is similar: put a node at a position close to the end of the path, at a length approximately equal to half of the arrow tip's width. Unfortunately, some manual adjustment of the `pos=<frac>` is needed (`<frac>` here is usually a number slightly smaller than `1`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-stealth'](0,0)..controls(.5,1)..(1,0) node(n)[pos=.98,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt]{};
  \draw[-stealth'](1,1)--(n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you!  I wonder if there's a way to automate this if the arrow is not horizontal.

Comment: @NeilG: I've updated my answer. It still requires some manual adjustment, however.

Comment: Nice, thanks!!  That's exactly what I was looking for.